# Manage threads using threadpool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

In C#, we can create threads as follows

```
    System.Threading.Thread thd1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(DoWork));
    thd1.Start();
    System.Threading.Thread thd2 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(DoWork));
    thd2.Start();
    thd1.Join();
    thd2.Join();
```

How can we manage threads similarly using ThreadPool, without using the statement above ?

Comment: Is it a C# related problem?

Comment: Yes. It is been done in c#. It is likely to have a number of procedures running in parallel; so I would like to use threadpool instead of managing individual threads, if possible.

Comment: So, use the ThreadPool class then, QueueUserWorkItem method.  Or more productively, use the Task or BackgroundWorker classes.  It is otherwise very unclear what you want to "manage".

Comment: Thanks. But if I call QueueUserWorkItem method, how will the threads kick in? How can we specify Priority, Join etc? Will the threads start and Join on their own?

Comment: The threads 'kick in' because the QueueUserWorkItem() call signals them.  There is no Join() required for threads that loop around a wait operation forever.  Priority?  If you require queued tasks to have different priorities, I'm not sure that a priority blocking queue is avaialable in BlockingCollection - you may have to roll your own threadpool to do that.

Comment: I get it. Thank you, Martin James

Answer (score 0):

There are many options in Java to use ThreadPoolExecutor, this is just one of them

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
...
executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     ...
  }
});
```